# Can I set Azure ML output to real JSON using Azure API Management?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-machine-learning-service

I have started using Azure ML to deploy ML service, but it sent results as raw text. I see Azure API Management can use to set outbound body. Can I use it to convert raw text to JSON? and how?

This is an example result from Azure ML WebService.

```
"{\"transcript\": \"\\u0e27\\u0e31\\u0e19\"}"
```

Another question, Can I decode UTF-8 in set-body policy?

Answer (score 0):

Now, I fixed this by making score.py return python dict instead of json.dumps().